# Is there a way to remove a certain number from a list?

Tags: python, list

like this:
I would like to remove a certain number of items

```
abc_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
abs_list =- 7
```

that should be the result

```
result = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: So you want to remove the last n elements from the list ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: What does 7 represent given that you are only removing 6 elements for the list ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative slicing to index from the back

```
>>> abc_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
>>> abc_list[:-6]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **slicing** to get a list with the first n elements.

```py
abc_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
# get a list with the first n elements (where the last m are removed)
first_3 = abc_list[:3]  # elements until the 3rd (inclusive), so n = 3
last_6_removed = abc_list[:-6] # elements until the 6th from back, so m = 6
```

In `[s:e]`  the `s` is the start index, the `e` is the end index. The *index* can be negative indicating reverse direction ("from back"). All elements between `s` and `e` are returned - *slicing*.

If the start or end is omitted, it will slice unbounded (without start or end as boundary).

See also:

Real Python: [Indexing and Slicing](https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/), tutorial